# How to extract date on X axis from a point on chart [mschart]

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, mschart

X axis type is `DateTime`. I want to know how to extract original `DateTime` value from the double value on the x axis corresponding to the point  in my series?

I can add point with

```
point->SetValueXY(xdateTime,yvalue);
chart1->Series[0]-Add(point);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this C# code, it should give you a start. I use it to add text to a `Label` thats shows the x value as date and the yvalue as a number. Hope this helps

[image: Chart Click GIF]

```
public void Cht_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
//Call HitTest()
HitTestResult result = sender.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

//If the mouse if over a data point
if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint) {
    //Reset Data Point Attributes
    DataPoint point = default(DataPoint);

    //Find selected data point
    point = result.Series.Points(result.PointIndex);

    //extract x value
    System.DateTime _date = System.DateTime.FromOADate(point.XValue);
    Label24.Text = "Date: " + Strings.Format(_date, "dd/MM/yy") + "    Value: " + point.YValues(0);

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was enough to FromOADate)